# Using cmake to create main and sub-projects, and be able to compile them individually

Tags: cmake

**DISCLAIMER:** I am new to CMakeLists.txt, I have a working implementation and would like to improve and enhance it, problem described below:

If I want `root/sub-directories/` as separate sub-projects that can be compiled using the individual `CMakeLists.txts` in their folders I find myself literally copy pasting almost the entire root file `CMakeLists.txt` per sub-directory.

I was wondering if there is a better way to have a main project and then sub-projects that get the shared dependencies from main project and can be compiled without `cmake`-ing the root `CMakeLists.txt`. My directory structure is;

CMakeLists.txt (root project)
| __ sub_dir-1
| __ | __ CMakeLists.txt (sub-project)
| __ sub_dir-2
| __ | __ CMakeLists.txt (sub-project)
| __ sub_dir-3
| __ | __ CMakeLists.txt (sub-project)
...

Essentially, I want to be able to:

1. `cmake root/CMakeLists.txt`, which creates an entire project that includes the sub-projects (I already have this implemented using individual CMakeLists.txts inside sub-directories.
2. `cmake root/sub-dir/CMakeLists.txt` and **only** compile the sub-project, which essentially also finds the necessary dependencies and includes them from maybe `.cmake` includes or `root/CMakeLists.txt`. What is the best way to approach this structure;

   - while retaining the first bullet point of having the ability to compile it as an entire project.
   - And also not *crowding* the `sub-dir/CMakeLists.txt` too much with redundant code?

Appreciate any suggestions! Thank you.

Comment: There are many ways for reduce copy pasting: `include()`, `function()`/`macro()`, variables. You may have subproject aware, whether they are build alone or as a part of root project via checking variables/targets/functions and take appropriate actions. Just try to program what you want.

Comment: There is a rather big difference between being able to configure (cmake) project individually and being able to compile (make) them individually. My experience is that you can get quite far by running cmake om the top directory and then specify what you want to build with make: `cmake <root-dir>; make sub-project1`. What is most important to you?

Comment: @Emil both are important actually, I want to be able to configure them using `cmake` and then compile using `make` as sub-projects as well as a main project.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I know there are many ways, I was hoping someone could point me to an efficient way, as I listed few restraints that I'd like to satisfy. Would you happen to have an example of this which I could follow?

Comment: *Efficiency* of one or another approach **highly depends from concrete situation** you have. The most efficient approach for one situation would be overcomplicated in other situations. Provide some (simplified) code, which is similar between your root project and subproject, and I (or someone else) will show the way you may reduce code duplicating.

Comment: I have the project on github, it is a huge project so I am not sure what I can simplify, but;
Root CMakeLists.txt: https://github.com/neoblizz/gunrock/blob/dev/CMakeLists.txt
Sub-Dir: https://github.com/neoblizz/gunrock/blob/dev/tests/bfs/CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There are a few strategies which may work, some of which could be combined.

**STRATEGY 1:**

If you are using the `Unix Makefiles` generator with CMake, then simply invoking `make` from the build output dir that corresponds to the subdirectory you want to build should largely accomplish what you describe. Targets from other directories won't get built unless they are needed by a target for the subdirectory you are building in (or a subdirectory below that). So while you do run CMake from the root directory, you still only build just the subdirectory(s) you want.

*Pros:* Easy, requires no changes to your `CMakeLists.txt` files.

*Cons:* Only works with `Unix Makefiles` generator, requires all parts of the source tree to be processed by CMake whether you want to build them or not.

**STRATEGY 2:**

As mentioned by @Emil in his comment to your question, you could simply just build the specific target(s) you want from the top level of your build output directory. This assumes you know the relevant targets you want to build though, or put another way, it requires you to have a good understanding of what targets are provided by which subdirectories.

*Pros:* Flexible, works with any CMake generator, requires no changes to your `CMakeLists.txt` files.

*Cons:* Requires some knowledge of what each subdirectory provides, requires all parts of the source tree to be processed by CMake whether you want to build them or not.

**STRATEGY 3:**

In the top level `CMakeLists.txt` file, you could make the `add_subdirectory()` call for each subdirectory depend on an option variable. This would allow you to turn inclusion of each subdirectory on or off individually, giving you precise control over what gets built. You could build everything, just one subdirectory or a set of subdirectories (more flexible than your requirements, but potentially useful).

Conditionally including a subdirectory with an option variable would typically be done something like this:

```
option(BUILD_SUBDIR1 "Enable building subdir1" ON)
option(BUILD_SUBDIR2 "Enable building subdir2" ON)

if(BUILD_SUBDIR1)
    add_subdirectory(subdir1)
endif()
if(BUILD_SUBDIR2)
    add_subdirectory(subdir2)
endif()
```

If some subdirectories depend on others, then the logic for whether to add a subdirectory or not would need to account for that (i.e. implement dependencies between options). It shouldn't be hard to do if required.

*Pros:* Flexibility to build precisely whatever set of subdirectories you want in one build, CMake only has to process those subdirectories you are interested in (saves time for huge project trees and allows you skip problematic parts of the project tree) and works for any CMake generator.

*Cons:* You need separate build directories if you want to build different subdirectories individually. You can't simply `cd` to a different part of your build output directory structure and run a build from there, for example. You still have just one source tree, but you have multiple build output trees. In practice, this may not be an issue depending on what you ultimately want to be able to do (I regularly have multiple build dirs for a given source tree, but that's usually for Debug and Release builds rather than different sets of CMake options). Also requires an understanding of dependencies between subdirectories. Requires mild changes to top level `CMakeLists.txt` file.

---

Hopefully one of the above options or some combination thereof gives you some ideas for how to ultimately achieve what you are aiming for. I had a quick look at the top level `CMakeLists.txt` in the github project you linked to and it looks like it already makes use of options like in strategy 3, just not quite to turn on/off individual subdirectories.

Comment: Yes Craig, I think we're already implementing option 3 to some extent, thanks a lot for your answer! A question is then, if people want to build just one specific project using that option command, is there a way to do it through terminal `cmake -option=project2` or something like that? Instead of changing `CMakeLists.txt` every time they wanna build a separate project?

Comment: The whole point of the `option()` command is precisely that. You can set the option when you invoke cmake like so: `cmake -DBUILD_SUBDIR1=ON`. CMake will remember that in its cache, so you don't have to keep specifying it thereafter when re-running cmake or doing your build  with make. The `option()` command takes a default value which is used if you don't set the option on the cmake command line.

Comment: Makes sense. Once again, thank you so much @Craig Scott!